# USB boot 18.10 works but not 16.04 (doesn't show in BIOS)

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb, live-usb, bios

First post, apologies for any errors.

I can successfully usb boot ubuntu 18.10, but I am unable to usb boot ubuntu 16.04.  The reason I am attempting to use 16.04 is because software I am required to work with is not yet compatible with 18.10.

My process is as follows: download ISO > universal usb installer > reboot > F2 to go to BIOS > apply bootup sequence change (UEFI) (I format usb when changing between the two versions)

When attempting to boot 16.04: usb option does not auto populate in the BIOS under 'boot sequence' like it does when booting 18.10. When I try to manually add boot option, I am prompted to:

1) type a random boot name in (eg 'boot')

2) option to select a usb file path from the file system list, which I do

3) select file name. I do not know which file name to select from the the file system (FS0, FS1) directories so I leave it blank.  When I save and reboot, the file name that auto populates in this field is '/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI'.

I did not disable secure boot/enable legacy settings prior to successfully booting 18.10, but I did alter these just to rule it out and I was still unsuccessful in booting 16.04.

Really struggling understanding why I'm having difficulty booting 16.04 if I'm able to successfully boot 18.10 no problems without variation in my process.  All help is really appreciated.

Dell Latitude 7480, Windows 7

Comment: It could be that your computer is too new for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Have you tried if the newer LTS version, 18.04.1 LTS, can manage your software? It could also be a problem with the installer, and that you could have better luck with a cloning tool, for example the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 18.10 in order to create a USB boot drive for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Depending on your computer and the software you need, have you thought about installing 16.04 on a virtual box hosted in 18.10? Could be a work around solution...

Comment: @sudodus I don't believe my computer is too new for 16.04, but I will look into a cloning tool.  Relatively new to this so I will have to investigate.

Comment: @Flot I am not familiar with a virtual box, but will look into this too.  Thanks, both!

Comment: Did you try 16.04.1 LTS or 16.04.6 LTS? And did you check with md5sum, that the iso file is downloaded correctly (no transfer error)? See the following links, http://releases.ubuntu.com/ and [help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)